# Prolog Summing up the last element in lists

Tags: recursion, prolog

I got several lists in my program as facts

```
road(1, 2, 3)
road(2, 3, 4)
```

Im trying to sum up the last elements in my lists. I know how i can get the last element with the `last/2` operator in Prolog. But how can i sum the last element of multiple road lists in a recursive way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in that way:

- Take all last elements and put them in a list:

  ```
  findall(X, road(_, _, X), L).
  ```
- Sum all element in the list:

  ```
  sum([], 0).
  sum([H|T], S1):- sum(T, S2), S1 is H + S2.
  ```

Summing up, the solution is as follow:

```
countLast(Sum):- findall(X, road(_, _, X), L), sum(L, Sum).
sum([], 0).
sum([H|T], S1):- sum(T, S2), S1 is H + S2.
```

Comment: thanks for the respond. How do I execute this in the terminal? i've tried sum([road(1,2,3),road(2,3,4)], X).

Comment: Hi, you have first to save the code in a prolog file like `test.pl` and then call it from the terminale with the `['test.pl'].` command.

Comment: Note that sum work with a list of numbers, not roads. You have to call it in this way: `sum([3, 4], X)`.

Comment: Hi, I've got it to sum up numbers but Like above I need a function that sums up given roads like sum([road(1,2,3),road(2,3,4)], X) and returns X.  How do I use countlast in your given example?

Comment: Then you have to change the code a bit: `countLast(Sum):- findall(road(X, Y, Z), road(X, Y, Z), L), sum(L, Sum).` and  `sum([road(_, _, H)|T], S1):- sum(T, S2), S1 is H + S2. `